# detect some details from hardwares of server by php

Tags: php, localhost

I want to make a program by php, then install it on a localhost for the user.
assume that the user doesn't know any thing from php any way and can't read and edit the php sources.

I want to fetch some things from hardware like cpu serial number,etc to make a software lock and force the user to register the php application on a specific website for control the usage and get amount of money annually.
So, how can I get the hardware information of the server by php?!

note : the localhost is made by xampp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

ps. the localhost is not made by xampp.